# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'searchable')

Tags: reactjs

I have created table using react that fetch data from Postgres SQL and render it.
cant understand what is the root cause for this error.
errors -
[enter image description here][1]

the table was create with an internal component.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

```
function ResultsFunction() {
    // set state
    
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    const columns = [{
        id: 0, //mandatory field for arrange columns
        dataField: 'test_name',
        text: 'test_name',
        sort: true,
        visible: true, // is column visible for arrange
      },{
        id: 1,
        dataField: 'dut_name',
        text: 'name',
        sort: true,
        visible: true, // is column visible for arrange
      }, {
        id: 2,
        dataField: 'dut_ip',
        text: 'ip',
        sort: true,
        visible: true
      }, {
        id: 4,
        dataField: 'load',
        text: 'load',
        sort: true,
        visible: true // is column visible for arrange
      }]
     
    // first data grab
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://12.12.12.12:9000/")
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then((data) => {
            //console.log(data.length)
            //setResults(data)
            setResults(mapResults(data))
          });
      }, []);
    //console.log(results.length)

    

    const mapResults = (results) => {
      return  (
        results.map((result, index) => (
        <li> 
        {results.id = {index}}
        {result.test_name}
        {result.dut_name}
        {result.dut_ip}
        {result.load}
        </li>
        ))
        );
    }


    console.log(columns)
    console.log(results)
      return (
        <TableWithSearch
        data={results}
        columns={columns}
        />
      
      );
    }

    export default ResultsFunction;
    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49bU4.png
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong, save an array of data in state and then loop it with HTML in it.

Comment: im not sure i got you, do you have an example maybe ?
for that, should i using class ? 
am i doing the map correct ?

Comment: I cannot tell you more without looking into your TableWithSearch component, can you provide the code of that component too?

Comment: unfortunately no, but if i dont use 'mapResults' function, this error disappear, but a new one about missing key appear.

Comment: the thing is you dont have to save your HTML into state, you just need to save array, then later you can itrate your array with html